# How is the number of unique viewers calculated as displayed on YouTube Studio?

Tags: youtube-api

I am using the API to visualize YouTube data, but the API does not support the Uniques metrics. However, the number of unique viewers is displayed on the YouTube Studio screen, so there is no doubt that they are calculating the number of unique viewers. How does YouTube calculate this number of unique viewers?